# Push database into Django

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I'm currently working on a project with Django, I have designed a model like

```
Class Item(models.Model):  
    id  
    name     
    ...
```

And I've already had a sqlite database with data like

```
Id, name, ...  
1, a, ...  
2, b, ...
```

Now, the question is how I can push this database to django? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You usually don't create any databases tables in the database per se, you just need to create the Django models and then run and apply the migrations. So, for instance, if you have the following model:

```
class Item(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

You just need to go to the terminal and type
`python manage.py makemigrations` (This will create a migration file)
`python manage.py migrate` (This will create the actual tables/columns in your database)

If you then open a shell:
python manage.py shell

and create an object via Django:

```
from yourapp.models import Item
Item.objects.create(name='Hello')
```

That Item should be saved to your DB.

Comment: Because the data I have is from web scraping and it is quite big, so I would like to add this data directly to the django database, so it is not possible ?